# Retain top-N elements as we loop across all elements

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures

Here is what I am trying to do. The output of a calculation on a dataframe gives a number. I use that number to rank the different dataframes and I need to retain the top-N (in the example below, the top 10 is chosen). The ranking is achieved by comparing the number to the last number of a reverse sorted list. If the current number is larger, the list is popped and the new entry added to the list followed by reverse sorting again. The following is structurally identical to what I have and it works, albeit slowly. I would appreciate any suggestions to improve its speed, efficiency or Pythonicness.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

def gen_df():
    return random.uniform(0.0, 1.0), pd.DataFrame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mylist = []
    for i in range(1000):
        val, df = gen_df()
        if len(mylist) < 10:
            mylist.append((val, df))
        else:
            mylist.sort(reverse=True)
            if mylist[-1][0] < val:
                mylist.pop()
                mylist.append((val, df))
```

EDIT: Reduced one sort after suggestion by zondo.

Comment: For one thing, I don't think you need to sort it every time.  Just sort it before you say `mylist.pop()` and sort it once you're done with it, outside the loop.

Comment: I am not sure about this. I am comparing the current value to the lowest value in the top 10. Without a sorted list, I will need more logic.

Comment: Yes, I could get replace both sorts with one after the else:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that, in Python, lists are really just pointers to the things they contain.  So certain list operations can be quite fast, even if the list contains some pretty heavy data structures (i.e. the DataFrames in your example).  Your approach involves making a small list (10 items long) and constantly modifying it to be "correct" as more DataFrames are "considered" for the top 10.  That feels a bit unnecessary to me.  I would just make one big list of all the candidates, sort it once, and take the first 10.  Also, appends are slower than insertions, so better to allocate the memory all at once.

My guess is that for big data sets, the approach I lay out below will be a bit faster.  But regardless, I find it a bit more readable.

```
def get_top_10_so():
    mylist = []
    for i in range(1000):
        val, df = gen_df()
        if len(mylist) < 10:
            mylist.append((val, df))
        else:
            mylist.sort(reverse=True)
            if mylist[-1][0] < val:
                mylist.pop()
                mylist.append((val, df))
    return mylist

def get_top_10_mine():
    mylist = [None] * 1000
    for i in range(1000):
        mylist[i] = gen_df()
    mylist.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0], reverse=True)
    return mylist[:10]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to speed it up is to replace your list with a min-heap of size 10. Put the first 10 frames into the heap. Then, for each item, if it's larger than the smallest item on the heap, pop the smallest item and push the new item.

I'm not a Python programmer, so I'll present the pseudocode.

```
heap = new min-heap
for each item
    if (heap.length < 10)
        heap.push(item)
    else if (item > heap.peek())
        heap.pop(); // remove smallest item
        heap.push(item); // add new item
```

This assumes, of course, that there's a min-heap implementation that you can use. I suspect [heapq](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) will do the trick.

That's going to be significantly faster than sorting the list every time you insert a new item.